# Assigning value to global variable in ReactJs ES5

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm new to Reactjs and I'm developing a simple application using React and SocketIO. I'm trying to declare a global variable and assign `{data.name}` value to it (code shown below).

```
socket.on('loginSuccess', function (data) {
if (data.type == 'teacher') {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <div><TeacherLayout userName={data.name}/></div>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
} else {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <div><StudentLayout userName={data.name}/></div>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
}
reactCookie.save('sid', data.id);
});
```

I want to pass the global variable to `userName` of the code shown below,

```
socket.on('sessionstart', function (data) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <div><MainLayout userName={globalVariable}/></div>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
}
reactCookie.save('sid', data.id);
 });
```

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: You could technically just assign it to a new property on the global window object, but it's not the best solution in most cases. If you provide more details about what you want to accomplish it's more likely people will be able to help you find more appropriate solutions :)

Comment: I have added more information on the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localstorage for this.

```
//Set your gloabal variable from any where in your app by
localStorage.setItem("key(variable-name)","value")
```

```
//Get your gloabal variable from any where in your app by
localStorage.getItem("key(variable-name)")
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!